# My string concatenation in JS isn't working

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two Strings, but its not doing anything and there are no errors in the console. So most likely I am too blind to see the problem ...
Here my code to get the two Strings:

```
$.get( "urlto/file.css", function(data) {
    cssOne = data;
    return cssOne;
}, "html");

$.get( "urlto/otherfile.css", function(data) {
    cssTwo = data;
    return cssTwo;
}, "html");
```

and here is the Method for the concatenation:

```
function mergeCSS(){
    cssText = cssOne+" "+cssTwo;
return cssText;
}
```

The variables are all global, so I dont think that this cause any problems.
As i said maybe I'm just blind ... Anyone knows why its not working?
Thx

Comment: post your full code, I think variables `cssOne` & `cssTwo` are not getting updated.

Comment: When are you calling `mergeCSS()`?

Comment: Depends on when you calling `mergeCSS()`

Comment: what is the output if you alert `cssText` ? Also When are you calling `mergeCSS()`?

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous (it's a wrapper for `$.ajax`) so the success functions are only called when the `$.get` has completed. Likely you are calling `mergeCSS` before they have completed.

Comment: Returning values from callbacks to asynchronous operations like `$.get()` doesn't have any effect. I strongly suspect that that's what your problem is here - you're trying to concatenate the strings before the responses have arrived.

Comment: the whole code would be a bit long i think.. The problem is when I alert() cssOne or cssTwo everything is fine and i got the single String, but when i alert cssText i only got cssOne ... And i also tried not to use an extra function and simply used text = one + two ... but this didnt work too

Comment: And i got an extra button to call my functions, including mergeCSS()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery is not synchronous. So you are not getting desired result. You can use **[Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/)** synchronous JavaScript.

You can do something like this:

```
$.get( "urlto/file.css", function(data) {
    cssOne = data;
    $.get( "urlto/otherfile.css", function(data) {
       cssTwo = data;
       var newCSS = mergeCSS();//call function here
    }, "html");
}, "html");

function mergeCSS(){
    cssText = cssOne+" "+cssTwo;
    return cssText;
}
```

**Update:** If you want to do this on button click you can do this like:

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(){
    $.get( "urlto/file.css", function(data) {
        cssOne = data;
        $.get( "urlto/otherfile.css", function(data) {
           cssTwo = data;
           var newCSS = mergeCSS(cssOne,cssTwo);//call function here
           alert(newCSS);
        }, "html");
    }, "html");
});

function mergeCSS(cssOne,cssTwo){
    cssText = cssOne+" "+cssTwo;
    return cssText;
}
```

Comment: the alert still contains only cssOne.

Comment: Note: This doesn't fire the `.get` to `/otherfile.css` until the first `.get` is complete. This makes this somewhat inefficient in this case and completely unmanageable if you had to fire many more `.get` requests.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deferred object race issue. Use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) for waiting for all promises to get resolved. You dont need callbacks in your case:

```
var p1 = $.get( "urlto/file.css", null, "html");
var p2 = $.get( "urlto/otherfile.css", null, "html");

$.when(p1,p2).done(function(r1,r2){
   cssText = r1 + r2;
});
```

Comment: +1: This is a much better answer than the accepted answer because it starts both requests immediately instead of having them be sequential.